# How do I check convergence of an infinite product divided by an infinite sum /// Is it possible?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

I am currently taking a class that involves studying circuits. We recently went over the equation for resistance in a circuit with parallel resistors, where $n$ is the total amount of resistors in parallel
$$
\frac{1}{R_{Total}} = \frac{1}{R_{1}}+\frac{1}{R_{2}}+\frac{1}{R_{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{R_{n}}.
$$
This is the equation I've derived from the parallel resistance formula. $R _i$ represents the resistance of resistor $i$, and $n$ represents the total amount of resistors in parallel. It solves for the total resistance.
$$
R_{Total}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}R_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}R_i\sum_{v=i+1}^{n}R_v}
$$

From this formula, taking it out of context, I have two questions:

1. Does this formula actually hold true?
2. If it does, suppose there were an infinite amount of resistors in parallel, where $n \to \infty$. Is it possible to check for the convergence of this whole statement?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could type up your question using mathjax. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide. It would make your question much more accessible/readable for everyone.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions instead of posting links.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In the infinite case, you should be easily able to come up with an example where $R_{Total}$ is defined in your top formula, but the infinite product in the second formula does not converge.

Comment: I seems pretty likely to me that it's going to be easier just to consider whether the original sum $1/R_1+1/R_2+\dots$ converges.